# Find and connect together contours of an unfinished shape

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image with a shape in it. For some reasons, findContours does not detect any contour in my image and I would like to know why. Also I made a shape myself in paint that is similar and for that shape the function works. The shape not being complete I was wondering if it's possible to "close" the shape via the contours.

[Here is the shape I made myself and trying to connect the unfinished lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPWv4.png)

[This is the image where the function doesn't detect the shape at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFIbn.png)

```
img = cv2.imread("crop4_2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 256), random.randrange(0, 255)), 50)
```

Comment: You can use morphology open with a horizontal kernel slightly larger than the gap to fill the black line of the boundary.

Comment: @fmw42 I've tried looking on how to use horizonal kernel but I could not find it. Could you provide me with a line of code if possible? Thank you

Comment: I cannot give you a solution using morphology that will fill in the gaps in your second image. The first image is easier since the gap is relatively short and horizontal and you can easily create a horizontal kernel. The second image is harder since the gap is large compared to the size of your figure and at a diagonal.